# Method of Passing Thread Parameters Causing Race Condition?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a question about a program I am writing, one which requires some multi-threading. The thread function requires a couple of parameters, which I am passing by doing the following:

1. Having a struct defined for the parameters (lets call it ThreadDataStruct)
2. Initializing this struct and filling the values (call our ThreadDataStruct instance THREAD_DATA)
3. Passing the values on to my thread during CreateThread by setting lpParameter to a pointer to the struct (&THREAD_DATA)
4. Re-cast the LPVOID to ThreadDataStruct in the thread function

The issue is that my function which creates the threads returns directly after the call to CreateThread. My question is: can returning so soon after creating the thread cause the thread to not get its parameters? If the struct was created in the function and then the function returns, won't the parameters for the thread function be destroyed if it can't get them fast enough?

Here is some POC to show what I mean:

Definition of our struct:

```
typedef struct ThreadDataStruct
{

    int Number;
};
```

Our function we are running inside:

```
void Function()
{

    ThreadDataStruct THREAD_DATA;
    THREAD_DATA.Number = 1;

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadFunction, &THREAD_DATA, 0, NULL);
    return;
}
```

Our thread function:

```
void ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{

    ThreadDataStruct THREAD_DATA = *(ThreadDataStruct *)lpParam;
    int NumberFromStruct = THREAD_DATA.Number;

    return;
}
```

Do I need to find another way to pass the parameters safely?

Comment: Yes, you have a race condition; and yes, you need to have a different way of passing the parameters to the function safely.  The variable passed to the thread function is (normally) passed by address, so it needs to last as long as the thread needs to access it.  In your code, the function returns and that means the variable is no longer valid, so all hell breaks loose.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for clearing that up. What methods are there to pass the parameters safely? I guess I could put a Sleep(5000) after CreateThread, but that obviously is not the best way to do this.

Comment: One option is to have `Function()` wait for the the thread to complete before it returns.  Another option is to have `Function()` wait on a semaphore, and the `ThreadFunction()` would signal on the semaphore when it has finished reading its control data.  Another option, probably the best, is to have the function that calls `Function()` pass in a `ThreadDataStruct *` that can be used, and for it to keep that around until all the threads have terminated.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ So, if it is `main()` that calls `Function()`, then `main()` might have an array of `ThreadDataStruct thread_params[32];` and it could pass `&thread_params[i]` to the `i`th call to `Function()` (probably within a loop).  No doubt there are other equivalent techniques available too; these come to mind immediately.  Normally, though, the controlling code has some sort of array of the data structures available, and passes one of the elements of the array to each invocation of the thread-launching function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

Yes, you have a race condition; and yes, you need to have a different way of passing the parameters to the function safely. The variable passed to the thread function is (normally) passed by address, so it needs to last as long as the thread needs to access it. In your code, the function returns and that means the variable is no longer valid, so all hell breaks loose.

> Thank you for clearing that up. What methods are there to pass the parameters safely? I guess I could put a `Sleep(5000)` after `CreateThread()`, but that obviously is not the best way to do this.

One option is to have `Function()` wait for the the thread to complete before it returns. Another option is to have `Function()` wait on a semaphore, and the `ThreadFunction()` would signal on the semaphore when it has finished reading its control data.

Another option, probably the best, is to have the function that calls `Function()` pass in a `ThreadDataStruct *` that can be used, and for it to keep that around until all the threads have terminated.  So, if it is `main()` that calls `Function()`, then `main()` might have an array of `ThreadDataStruct thread_params[32];` and it could pass `&thread_params[i]` to the `i`<sup>th</sup> call to `Function()` (probably within a loop).

```
void Function(ThreadDataStruct *THREAD_DATA)
{
    THREAD_DATA->Number = 1;

    CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunction, THREAD_DATA, 0, NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    ThreadDataStruct thread_params[32];

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        Function(&thread_params[i]);

    …code to wait for threads to exit…
}
```

Changes in `Function()` include:

- Add argument.
- Initialize argument via pointer.
- Pass argument directly, not `&THREAD_DATA`.
- Don't cast the thread function pointer type; make sure `ThreadFunction()` is the correct type to be called by `CreateThread()`.
- There's no virtue in a `return;` at the end of a `void` function.

No doubt there are other equivalent techniques available too; these come to mind immediately. Normally, though, the controlling code has some sort of array of the data structures available, and passes one of the elements of the array to each invocation of the thread-launching function.